Why wouldn't Wojciech give Stanislav Bronikovsky a new identity?
In Chapter 1, Viktor visits the increasingly-ailing Stanislav Bronikovsky in the infirmary. Stanislav indicated to Viktor that someone named Wojciech was supposed to give him a new identity and take him elsewhere on his yacht. However, he indicated Wojciech wouldn't take him in his current state. Why was this?

Bronikovsky was very ill at the time. Whether it was a physical illness, or whether, as he suspected, he was being poisoned, he was very weak and did not expect to live much longer. It makes no sense for a dying man to make the trip, which is why he asked Viktor to go in his stead. In the letter to his wife that he asks Viktor to take to her, he explicitly writes that he didn't expect to live much longer:

Darling Marina,
A thousand apologies. I’m far away, and clearly here to stay... alas, when you get
this, I shall be no more. In some strange way they’ve got at me even
here. Through the cook. All night I’m in agony but by morning it
eases. I wish the sods had gone for something short and sharp, instead
of making sure I suffer.

 Bolding mine 
The prediction turns out to be true, as in the rest of the book Bronikovsky's wife is referred to as his widow.
